# how to add pick color option to clip board manager?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

hi I want to add some option for text highlighting in the clipboard manager. I set the android:textisSelectable=true; now when I long click on text only two options comes one is for copy and other for select all. can I add the third option in that like pick a color and highlight the selectable text? or anyother simple way to do this? here is the image

[image]